# Move file change from one commit to the working copy

Tags: git

Let's say I just made `commit1` that had two changes:

- modified `fileA.txt`
- modified `fileB.txt`

Then I realized I made a mistake - I wasn't ready to commit my `fileB.txt` changes! I want the `fileB.txt` modifications to be in my working copy, and I want to amend the previous `commit1` to only have `fileA.txt` modifications. So the final outcome is:

`commit1`

- modified `fileA.txt`

`working copy`

- modified `fileB.txt`

What's the best way to achieve this? Is it possible to do this without changing branches?

Answer (score 4):

Sure..... do this:

```
git reset --soft HEAD~1 # asking git to move the branch _pointer_ one revision back.... files won't change, both files will end up on index
git reset fileB.txt # take fileB out of index
git commit -m "Here´s the revision, only fileA is affected"
```

And now fileB is modified on the working tree. Another way would be:

```
git checkout HEAD~ -- fileB.txt # get fileB as it was before
git commit --amend --no-edit
git checkout HEAD@{1} -- fileB.txt # get fileB from the previous broken revision
git commit -m "some comment"
```

That should work. (Use the revision ID on the second commit if you don't feel confident of using the reference with `HEAD@`. The revision ID can be seen in `git reflog`)

Comment: Is there a way to do it without having to recreate the commit message?

Comment: added another way to do it amending the current revision

Comment: The second way does not leave you with the modifications to fileB in the working copy.

Comment: ok... completed the recipe so you create the second revision with the file from the broken revision.

Answer (score 0):

I found a quite simple method (with the help of the other answer), which doesn't need to recreate the commit message.

`git reset HEAD~ -- fileB.txt`

Now the positive changes are in the working directory and the **negative** changes are staged (*i.e.* in the index). So the working directory isn't changed.

`git commit --amend --no-edit`

Negative changes are pushed, in other words, the file is removed from the commit but it's still in the working directory.

That's it.